# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory react-native

Tags: java, react-native

i have installed the openjdk11 with  [Chocolatey](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/) and set **JAVA_HOME** TO `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin` but when i try to run the command npx react-native run-android it give and error

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

it was working fine 2 weeks ago but now its not working .

Comment: There should be no '\bin' in JAVA_HOME. It's the *installation* directory. OTOH, it *can* be in PATH, by prepending ```%JAVA_HOME%\bin;```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no '\bin' in `JAVA_HOME`. It's the installation directory. OTOH, it can be in `PATH`, by prepending `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` That will mean that your new installation (defined by `JAVA_HOME`) will take precedence for execution.

Comment: I have working react-native AVDs. My "JAVA_HOME" is set to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre    and   "Path" variable is having C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.17.8-hotspot\bin     Tell me pls, should I change JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.17.8-hotspot  ??